make: *** [Makefile:604: all-recursive] Error 1
I am downloading grib_api for flexpart model. Try to make after
tar xvzf grib_api-1.28.0-Source.tar.gz
mkdir grib_api
cd grib_api-1.28.0-Source
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/grib_api --with-jasper=/usr/local/jasper

And then it is said as given by the title.
For detail, there seems to be a bunch of type mismatch between actual argument at (1) an actual argument at (2) (xxxxx/xxxxxx)

Please contact the developer of the software

This INSTALL file suggests that the autotools build is deprecated and that you should use cmake

... you may need to add -DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS=-std=legacy or at least -DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS=-fallow-argument-mismatch to the cmake command line for older and/or non-conformant Fortran code
